# Shared memory takes gigabytes

Tags: ram, xserver, shm

I have problems with huge RAM consumption by an unknown entity. It is not listed in `top`, but the amount of memory available decreases over time and turning off all programs does nothing. Currently, it's 3.6 GiB, but it's slowly getting worse. Probably as a result, the system is not capable to swap out much memory, after swapping out about 1.5 GiB of memory, it proceeds to thrashing.

I have used the `free -m` command to get this result:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7875        3517         388        3595        3969         481
Swap:          9536         500        9036
```

It seems that shared memory takes 3.5 gigabytes.

This is what I get when I run `df -h`:

```
udev                 3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                788M   80M  709M  11% /run
/dev/sdb6             23G   18G  4,1G  81% /
tmpfs                3,9G  168M  3,7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1            356M   76M  281M  22% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb8             37G   33G  2,0G  95% /home
/dev/sda2            746G  269G  477G  37% /data
/dev/sda3            184G  132G   43G  76% /lindata
tmpfs                788M   84K  788M   1% /run/user/1000
/home/dugi/.Private   37G   33G  2,0G  95% /home/dugi
```

`/proc/meminfo/` contains this, it seems that it's really something in shared memory:

```
MemTotal:        8064776 kB
MemFree:          318880 kB
MemAvailable:     493992 kB
Buffers:           36784 kB
Cached:          3960388 kB
SwapCached:        32776 kB
Active:          3732236 kB
Inactive:        3539036 kB
Active(anon):    3562316 kB
Inactive(anon):  3381848 kB
Active(file):     169920 kB
Inactive(file):   157188 kB
Unevictable:         732 kB
Mlocked:             732 kB
SwapTotal:       9765884 kB
SwapFree:        9253044 kB
Dirty:               516 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       3269552 kB
Mapped:           493840 kB
Shmem:           3670056 kB
Slab:             264136 kB
SReclaimable:     136840 kB
SUnreclaim:       127296 kB
KernelStack:       23296 kB
PageTables:        82464 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    13798272 kB
Committed_AS:   20782644 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    831488 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:     1783952 kB
DirectMap2M:     6498304 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

However, when I list the stuff in shared memory using `ipcs --human`, I get only a few hundreds of megabytes of deleted memory:

```
------ Message Queues --------
key        msqid      owner      perms      size         messages    

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      size       nattch     status      
0x00000000 268959744  dugi       600        386,8K     2          dest         
0x00000000 265879554  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 557059     dugi       600           16M     2          dest         
0x00000000 6258692    dugi       600            1K     2          dest         
0x00000000 271974405  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 31784966   dugi       600           16M     2          dest         
0x00000000 819207     dugi       600           16M     2          dest         
0x00000000 274464776  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 28704777   dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 274694154  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 264372236  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 272465933  dugi       600            4M     2          dest         
0x00000000 145522702  dugi       600           16M     2          dest         
0x00000000 274563088  dugi       600          7,6M     2          dest         
0x00000000 113934353  dugi       600           74K     2          dest         
0x00000000 215908370  dugi       600         66,2K     2          dest         
0x00000000 35913747   dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 274595860  dugi       600          7,6M     2          dest         
0x00000000 149946389  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 273842198  dugi       600          128M     2          dest         
0x00000000 115015703  dugi       600         29,3K     2          dest         
0x00000000 150044696  dugi       600           64M     2          dest         
0x00000000 143425561  dugi       600         32,5K     2          dest         
0x00000000 150011930  dugi       600            1M     2          dest         
0x00000000 149749788  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 149848094  dugi       600           64M     2          dest         
0x00000000 149815327  dugi       600            1M     2          dest         
0x00000000 166363168  dugi       700          2,2M     2          dest         
0x00000000 166395937  dugi       600          384K     2          dest         
0x00000000 166428706  dugi       600          512K     2          dest         
0x00000000 166461475  dugi       700         53,5K     2          dest         
0x00000000 166625316  dugi       700        376,6K     2          dest         
0x00000000 166658088  dugi       700         13,5K     2          dest         
0x00000000 166690857  dugi       700         88,7K     2          dest         

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems
```

If I use `ipcs -m | awk '{sum+=$5} END{print sum}'`, it says there's 366790104 bytes, which is 366 MB. This is far less than what it occupies.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 upgraded to 17.04. The problem was there already before the upgrade. Programs I use almost constantly are QtCreator, Vivaldi, evince, gcc, and the usual ones like gnome shell, nautilus or gedit.

The memory is never swapped out, I can't google a way to find the cause or just to delete it once per day or force swap it or something, I don't want to restart my computer several times per week. Any ideas what can be the problem?

EDIT: I have seen it suck up about 120 megabytes of memory for no known reason. I had Vivaldi (that makes extensive use of shared memory) shut down at that time because I was suspecting it of using causing the problem. The only thing I did at that time is that opened up Firefox for the first time after last restart (Firefox alone cannot be the cause because I didn't run it before those gigabytes got filled).

EDIT #2: Restarting the X-server removes the stuff from shared memory, but  that isn't a solution because the X-server is exactly the thing I don't want to restart (gnome-shell --replace doesn't help). If I remember the lessons about shared memory correctly, this means that the memory is grabbed by something related to the X-server or Gnome-shell that correctly frees it on exit, but never erases it while running (some sort of broken garbage collection?).

Edit #3: I wonder if it's related this: https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/3931

Comment: When you use `gcc`, are you developing and compiling your own software? Could there be memory problems with any of the programs that you are compiling?

Comment: I am not using shared memory in any program. There may be regular memory leaks, but that's cleared when the program exits.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe smemstat will show the memory hogger(s).  Use:

```
sudo apt-get install smemstat
sudo smemstat
```

Comment: After a restart, there isn't enough leaked shared memory yet, so I can't state conclusively if `smemstat` helped and what it is. The total it shows is for some reasons far greater than the amount of used shared memory announced by `free`, I think that either some memory is listed multiple times or swapped shared memory is not shown. I will reply after some time to tell if it was the cause.

Comment: Okay, so I observed it happening. I had no issues for a long time, but then it happened again. 1456 MiB in shared memory, `smemstat` lists only unremarkable stuff that amounts to less than 2 gigabytes in total, which is quite different from what `free` shows. Are you sure smemstat does the trick? Here is what I got: https://pastebin.com/MhZAWtWU